# Does okio FileHandle have something similar to RandomAccessFile.getchannel() in java?

Tags: okio

My problem is if the buffer is split, I want to make it contagious. In java, I used FileChannel for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

See the [FileHandle API](https://square.github.io/okio/3.x/okio/okio/okio/-file-handle/index.html), which has `source()` and `sink()` methods to read or write sequentially. If you call `sink().buffer()` the result implements `WritableByteChannel` and `source().buffer()` implements `ReadableByteChannel`.